# Android service won't start - in manifest... but nothing?

Tags: java, android, service

### UPDATE:

After adding the suggested methodes (`doBindService()` and `doUnbindService()`) along with calls to no avail) From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) suggested by @Nick Campion

I've been trying for a while to get this service running but nothing seems to be working - I know I'm probably missing a semicolon or something :)

The program calls `startNotificationService()`, then the Log shows the log message... and the app continues to run without the Service showing up. I can't find the Service in Advance Task Killer. HELP!!!

### XML (In Manifest) :

```
    <service 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="Smart Spdate Service"
        android:name="notifyService">
    <intent-filter 
        android:label="FULL_PATH_NAME_HERE.updateService">
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

### Service Call

```
    Log.v("NOTICE", "Notification Service was not found running - starting");
    //startService(new Intent(this, notifyService.class));
    startService(new Intent(notifyService.class.getName()));
    //startService(new Intent(TweetCollectorService.class.getName()));

     /* FROM GOOGLE */
     void doBindService() {
    // Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
    // class name because we want a specific service implementation that
    // we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
    // supporting component replacement by other applications).
    this.bindService(new Intent(this, updateService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        // Detach our existing connection.
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}
/* END OF GOOGLE CODE */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    web.close();
    doUnbindService(); // Added to `onDestroy` - suggested by Google page
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("NOTICE", "PROGRAM TERMINATED");
}
```

## updateService.java

```
public class updateService extends Service {
private String TAG = "SERVICE";
public static final int INTERVAL = 60000;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private static updateService Pointer;

public updateService() {
    Pointer = updateService.this;
}

public static class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    static updateService getService() {
        return Pointer;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            doStuff();
        }
    }, 0, INTERVAL);
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

public void doStuff() {
    Log.v(TAG, "doStuff");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where your client binds to your service.  Take a look at the [local service example.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample).  The reason for using the bind pattern even though you call startService is because the startService call is asynchronous.  You need to make an additional call to bind the service to make sure you get a call back once the startup is complete.

I've found that a really great example of a service [client](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/trunk/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/ListenView.java) and [service](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/trunk/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/PlaybackService.java) are available in the [NPR Open Source App](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/) for you to learn from!

Comment: I tried adding the Google code and took a look at the NPR code - but nothing is helping.

Comment: I'm having some formatting issues and losing a lot of your client class above, could you try to update that?

Comment: is there any logcat output of any variety?  `adb logcat *:D`

Comment: also, try to put logging in the bind callback inside your object `mConnection`

Comment: I'm using Eclipse - and the program logs perfectly (but not the service). This is not my first time making a service - I have a program that I've copied over with no luck. I don't need to bind it as it is going to be a timer and schedule an update of content gained online.

Comment: The ServiceCall section isn't very clear, but my concern is that you do need to bind because getting the callback in your mConnection is the only way you know the Service is ready for a call.  CAlling startSErvice tells the OS to start the service, but its non-blocking and the OS may take a moment to actually bring up the service.  Obviously, there could be other issues.  Try directly pasting in that service from the BBC and stripping out its functionality.  I know it works, so starting from that point may be easier then fiddling with something that may have other issues.